# How to reference TFS item within multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, source-control-explorer

I have a C# solution I created within Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate that contains multiple projects that make use of the same structures, classes, and enumerated types.  I have created a .cs file that contains all of these items, but at the moment I have to make a duplicate of this file for each project.  This is obviously less than ideal because I have to remember to update each copy of the file should I make a change or addition.

Is there are way I can have all of the projects reference just one actual copy of this file, so that I only have to update it once and all of the other projects can see this update?  A colleague of mine told me it was possible to make some sort of "symbolic" reference in TFS, but since I don't really know what the name of this feature is I don't know how to research it further.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666898/share-c-sharp-class-source-code-between-several-projects) has answers that suggest either creating a class library or using "Add as link" when adding an existing item.  I suppose I can do this in Visual Studio when not using TFS, but I have posed this as a TFS-specific question.  Will this "add as link" option work when TFS is in use or do I have to do something in TFS to get it to honor the link reference?

Comment: How funny.  I earned a "popular question" badge for this question yet haven't even managed to get a single upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Add link" option would definitely work with TFS. You dont have to do anything specific for that. "Add Link" is project specific and it will add a new entry to your project file specifying the location of your .CS file. As long as the file is available in the particular location during server build, there is nothing to worry. Make sure that the Add link makes a relative path to the file and not absolute.

In my company, we have multiple projects within a solution and we share a single "Assemblyversion.cs" for all the projects so that I dont need to write version info in multiple files. We have made use of Add Link and it works great!

Comment: What happens if you use "Add Link" from a project in TFS to a project that isn't in TFS?

Comment: You mean a file which is not in TFS? If you add a ".cs" file in your project and forget to check-in that .cs file to TFS, then your server build (and also the builds in other developer machines) will fail stating that it cant find the .cs file. Same way if you addlink  file in your project and if it is not present in TFS, then the build will fail.

Comment: I've tested this method and it works well.  Just to be clear, in the first project, use the Solution Explorer to Add New Item. Then Check-in this item.  Then in the second project, from Solution Explorer, choose Add Existing Item, and browse to the first project, and ENSURE you choose the dropdown choice on the dialog that is 'Add as Link'.  Now this is managed by TFS source Control. This works for me in VS 2013 Ultimate with a TFS 2010 back end.