# How can I design Microservice so that it retrieves data from two tables whose entities have already been defined in another microservice?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, architecture, microservices

I have developed a single solution that integrates several projects as a micro-services.
Every micro-service points to the same database.

I'm using the Entity Framework.

According to the picture below -

[image]

micro-service 1 has entity 1 and retrieves data from table 1. In a similar manner, micro-service 2 has entity 2 and retrieves data from table 2.

Now I have micro-service 3 and micro-service 3 wants data that needs to be joined between Table 1 and Table 2 but I have already created related entities (for table 1 and table 2) on other micro-services(micro-service 1 and micro-service 2). So how can I get those data on micro-service 3 ?

If I need the data from table 1 and table 2  on micro-service 3 then need to create a same entity on micro-service 3 but it will create repetitive entities and its opposite of DRY principle.

Question: How can I design Micro-service 3 so that it retrieves data from two tables whose entities have already been defined in another micro-service?

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me solving this doubt!

Comment: I try not to be that guy, but from all I hear, if your microservices access a shared database, you’re doing microservices wrong. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2GlRToY5HI
But of course you can do this. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: In general, microservices are not DRY at the very least when it comes to data, that’s their whole point. Purist microservices would not repeat the entity definition per se, but every service would store its own data, leading to much duplication. The upside is that you don’t have to touch multiple services when making schema changes, so it’s more conducive to splitting work between isolated teams. Your architecture doesn’t have this advantage.

Comment: @BenderBoy You are right each microservice should have a common database but due to client requirements, the database should be the same so implementing that way...Now I'm struggling with the change of one microservice should not affect another microservice and also get data from the database using join which entity is available on different microservices how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: you can create a common library where you keep all your entities, and then import that library in all 3 services. This way you reuse code. In C# this is done with a [class library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666898/share-c-sharp-class-source-code-between-several-projects), in JVM apps you need to create a JAR file.

Now as a side-note, in a classical microservices architecture, each microservice has its own database, which brings the benefits of scalability, separation of concerns and others (that doesn't mean you can't play around and learn stuff by exploring things)

Comment: If I developed a class library, let's say I have 20 microservices, but due to modifications in a class library, we need to deploy all of them because there is a shared common class library. Is there any way that if one microservice changes, the other microservice will not change?

Comment: I assume the class library artifact has a version number, and in your microservice you import a specific version of the class library. You update the class library version only when you need the latest changes, your are not forced to do that everywhere.