# How to reference a C# Class Library project in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am new to visual studio and was wondering how to setup visual studio 2010 so that I can reference my C# windows class library project? I currently have a solution with 2 projects - C# library project and a unit test project.

What is the best way to create multiple clients that will use this library? Should they be their own solution or just another project in the library solution? How do I use the classes in the library function from the project that references the library project?

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add a reference to a library by doing a rightclick on the references node in the solution explorer and selecting the req. lib...

When all you consuming apps are located within the same solution I would prefer to place the lib also inside the sln, otherwise I would use an extra sln

Comment: A simple way to solve a problem I was finding quite complicated.  2 1/2 years later, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

**Right click on the Client project "References" - > Add Reference** 
Go to the Projects tab if the class library is in the same solution. Else Browse and select the dll of the class library.

If Class library is not going to release as common dll for multiple projects, it's better to add them all to the same solution.