# Visual Studio 2015 Class Library (I'm using C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, class-library

I am working on a Windows Service Application.  I have several classes in the project and I am trying to put these classes into a ClassLibrary so I can use those classes in the Service App Project, and also in a Console Application Project, so I can run the console version and step through the code. I don't want to re-invent the wheel here...

I have created a Class Library project, and I am having trouble updating the projects in this Solution to use these classes.  In fact, when I moved all my classes into the Class Library project, they are all now throwing errors saying, "System" has no member "Data"!  My A$$ it doesn't!  Pulling my hair out.

Obviously, I have done something wrong.  I've been programming since before there WAS a Visual Studio IDE, but this is SEEMING way more complicated than it should be.

Now my Service project cannot reference my Class Library project because the library doesn't have a .dll or .exe extension?  I actually have to specify this somewhere, WhereTF do I do this?  Isn't this the default behavior of a ClassLibrary?  OMG!  I just finished an iOS application, and NEVER thought that would be EASIER than a C# app!  I did this in VS2010 easily, is 2015 really different?

It should take me no more than 30 minutes to move files from one project in a solution to it's own project, and then add a reference to that new project in the old one.  Giving MS a MegaMindWedgie right now..

Don't need portability with RT hardware, just want 32-bit/64-bit computer apps.

All 3 projects are using the same namespace.  I can't seem to add any references to the ClassLibrary project like I can in the Service project.  It's blank.  The only reference available to the Class Library project is .NETStandard,Version=v1.6

[image: All I see when I choose Add->Reference]

HELP...

Comment: This was answered before, [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228335/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-a-project), [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586243/how-do-i-install-a-c-sharp-class-library-in-visual-studio) & [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606217/how-to-reference-a-c-sharp-class-library-project-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: DId you perhaps added a .net core class library?

Comment: I've done this in VS2010 but then it was a "DLL project" .   Something is FUBAR'd with the VS2015 ClassLibrary project default settings because the Assembly info is all blank, there are no AddReference options, and when I build it, NO dll is being created.

Comment: Ahmed I. Elsayed :  I've done this all in VS2010, VS2016 is doing something COMPLETELY DIFFERENT  I did exactly what your links say to do.  I can't add anything...

Comment: Every single time I deal with Microsoft, i turn into TorretDave!  Tower of Babel needs to fall....

Comment: In your Windows service app, when you Add Reference, you should see 4 options: Assemblies, Solution, COM, Browse. What happens when you select Solution and under that "Projects" and then tick the ClassLibrary project and click OK? The ClassLibrary project is part of the Solution, right?

Comment: I did and it says that you cannot add a reference to something that isn't a dll or exe.  The template for ClassLibrary is completely screwed up.  I've killed it and recreated it twice now, and it's not even trying to build a dll or exe

Comment: I cannot add any references for frameworks I need for the classes in the ClassLibrary beyond what's in the default .NETStandard,Version=v1.6, so none of them will compile.

Comment: I've done this a hundred times myself, but something is really screwed up, and I am seeing many other posts like this, which leads me to believe that my install is somehow screwed up, and when I create a ClassLibrary project, because the Template is screwed up, it's not setting up the project correctly, so I cannot add any references to anything that isn't in the .NETStandard,Version=v1.6 library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have created .NET Core class library. You can determine this based on the extension of the project file: *.csproj has been used with classic .NET framework projects, and *.xproj was introduced for .NET Core. Most probably, you don't need a .NET Core class library. So, your problem will go away if you create .NET Framework Class Library project.

Comment: You are right, but I didn't CHOOSE core .NET, going back and looking at the options, I only see Class Library (Universal Windows) option.  I will try that...

Comment: Nope.  I need really old compatibility for this project.  I am coding to use a really old AccessDB (.mdb) file, and the minumum build for this option was Windows 10 versions...  Maybe becasue i am using Windows10 this is what I'm seeing.  I miss my old Windows 7 system,

Comment: right-click on your project, select properties, search for a Target Framework or something similar

Comment: The project I created just won't let me change any of that.  I created a ClassLibrary from the ClassicWindows sub heading and now I have the libs I need to add.

Comment: basically tossed out my whole morning.  Starting again..  happens a lot in MS world....  But if management had listened to me 4 years ago and let me update the Manufacturing systems away from the WindowsXP systems still in place, I wouldn't have a pile of hair on the floor right now.

Comment: I believe you should be able to create "old" csproj class library. I don't have .NET Core tooling at the moment, so can't check, but carefully look at the options when you are creating a new project, and try to choose .Net Framework. Good luck! :|