# Referencing javascript components in another project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, build-automation, projects-and-solutions

I'm currently developing several web projects in Ext JS and ASP.NET using Visual Studio 10. During that process, I have developed several javascript GUI components, some of which I use in more than one web project. Now, when I make any changes to one of these components, I would like them to automatically appear in all of the projects they are used in. I also would very much like to be able to have these components in their own respective projects / solutions.

When building my main ASP.NET web application which uses my components A and B, their javascript code would then have to be copied into the web application's output folder.

It's no problem to do such things with C# assemblies - you can just reference the needed DLLs. But it amazes me that I'm not being able to find a way to do something similar with javascript code (or, more general, with any sort of static files)!

Has anyone dealt with this problem before and found a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have wondered the same thing.

You can share projects across solutions (including those controlled by TFS, although I imagine there are limitations to this). I've read about this working for static files (like script) but I haven't gotten around to trying it. It doesn't seem ideal for all cases. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio) discusses how to "add as link", which might be useful.

I've recently set up a separate VS solution just for my JavaScript/CSS libraries with full source and a build/minification process. The final output is "compiled" and ready to go. I have also built out sample pages for each component and documentation. These samples serve also serve as great tests, because I can easily test for correct behavior in dozens of different scenarios.

It would be easy to write a script (or even a `FileSystemMonitor`, if you wanted to be fancy) to copy these final files into other project directories. Automatic copying won't always be the right answer, because you may want to have different solutions using different versions of your JS components. Manually copying isn't so bad, because you are usually only doing it when you have found and fixed a bug, or you are deploying a new version.

I would be interested in what other people are doing.