# How should I use Nuget for internal enterprise development?

Tags: nuget

We use Nuget for our internal development to allow us to share code across teams. We run into issues however when one person is working on code that will be deployed across multiple nuget packages at the same time. For instance

A depends on B which depends on C.

A, B and C have their artifacts pushed to Nuget and that's how we manage the dependencies between A, B and C. The trouble we find is that if a developer wants to make changes in C and quickly see those changes reflected in A, they have to go through the following process.

1. Make change in C.
2. Push change up to git
3. CI picks up change to C and builds and deploys new nuget package.
4. Go into B and update reference to C using a nuget update package command.
5. Push up the change to the packages.config file up to git
6. CI picks up change to B and builds and deploys new nuget package for B
7. Now open A and change reference to B and nuget update package
8. Make changes in A to go along with the changes in B(and transitively C)

This seems extremely painful and is causing some of our developers to question the choice of Nuget for our internally developed code. Everyone still like it for consuming external packages.

Is there any better workflow for using Nuget internally?

Comment: Still use it and really like it.  For us, when you build the code a script sends the package straight to a local NuGet file share.  That's great because the other projects can pick it up in their project with a NuGet update.  I think yours is a little tougher, not necessarily because of NuGet but because of the 3 layer dependency.  If you take NuGet out of the equation, you're still having to do the painful part of your process.

Comment: I think you need a 'glue' package to add a higher level of abstraction.  This package will reference the correct A, B, and C package versions.  Then projects only target glue.1.0.0, glue.2.0.0 etc

Comment: You could consider to design interface between various packages in a way that upgrade of the C does not necessarily mean you need to change the B. If it only [strong name/version issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies), you could take a look at [binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element).

Answer (score 43):

In our company we have solved the cascading updates problem with the following setup. First we have the following setup for our NuGet repositories and build server.

- There is an internal NuGet repository that holds all the published packages for the company. This repository is just a shared directory on one of our servers.
- Each developer can have (but doesn't need to have) one or more directories on their own machine that serves as a local NuGet package repository. By using a user specific NuGet [configuration](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1) the developer can control in which order NuGet searches through the package repositories to find packages.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <packageRestore>
      <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <packageSources>
      <add key="Dev" value="D:\dev\testpackages" />
      <add key="Company" value="<UNC_ADDRESS_COMPANY_REPOSITORY>" />
      <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    </packageSources>
    <disabledPackageSources />
    <activePackageSource>
      <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
  </configuration>
  ```
- All solutions have automatic package restore turned on, so that we don't have to commit the packages to our version control system.
- Developers only control 3 out of the 4 version numbers, e.g. if the version is `<MAJOR>.<MINOR>.<BUILD>.<REVISION>` then developers can only change the major, minor and build numbers, the revision number is set to 0 except in builds done by the build server where it is the build number of the build. This is important because it means that for a given version consisting of a major, minor and build number the build server will always produce the higher version number. This again means that NuGet will prefer to take the package version coming from the company package repository (which only gets packages through the build server).

In order to make a change to one of the base libraries there are two possible processes being used. The first process is:

1. Make the changes to the base library (A). Update the version of (A) if needed.
2. Run the MsBuild script to build the binaries and create the NuGet packages of (A)
3. Copy the new NuGet packages over to the package repository on the local machine
4. In the dependent project (B) upgrade to the new packages of (A) that were just placed in the local machine package repository (which should be of a higher version than the ones available on the company wide repository, or NuGet.org)
5. Make the changes to (B).

If more changes are required to (A) then repeat steps 1,2 and 3 and then delete the package of (A) from the working directory of (B). Next time the build runs NuGet will go looking for the specific version of (A), find it in the local machine repository and pull it back in. Note that the [NuGet cache](https://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Machine%20Level%20Cache%20Part%201) may thwart this process some of the time, although it looks like NuGet may not cache packages that come from the same machine(?).

Once the changes are complete, then we:

1. Commit the changes to (A). The build server will run the integration build to verify everything works.
2. Tell the build server to run the release build, which builds the binaries and pushes the NuGet packages to the company-wide NuGet repository.
3. In (B), upgrade to the latest version of (A) (which should have a higher version number than the test package because the test package should have version a.b.c.0 while the newly build version in the company-wide repository should be a.b.c. where  > 0
4. Commit the changes to (B). Wait for the build server to finish the integration tests
5. Tell the build server to run the release build for (B).

Another way of doing the development work is by taking the following steps

1. Make the changes to the base library (A). Update the version of (A) if required.
2. Build the binaries
3. Copy the binaries over to the location where NuGet unpacks the package of (A) for project (B) (e.g. `c:\mysource\projectB\packages\ProjectA.1.2.3.4`)
4. Make the required changes to project (B)

The commit process is still the same, project (A) needs to be committed first, and in project (B) the NuGet reference to (A) needs to be upgraded.

The first approach is slightly neater because this process also warns if there are faults in the NuGet package of (A) (e.g. forgotten to add a new assembly) while in the second process the developer won't know until after the package for (A) has been published.

Comment: See my edited answer above: shared code needs to go into its own package, not be distributed across multiple packages. This is a package management fundamental.

Comment: @MatthewSkelton I am not sure what you mean with 'shared code needs to go into its own package'. In my answer I assumed there would be separate packages for each of the products A, B and C. Obviously there may be multiple packages for any of the products but that wouldn't change the answer. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi Petrik, see the new edits to my answer above. Basically, changes to one package should not necessitate changes in another package, if the package boundaries are appropriate. Matthew

Comment: A third way to develop may be to use the http://nugetreferenceswitcher.codeplex.com VS extension, which automatically switches NuGet references to project references and back...

Comment: Can a developer have multiple local Nuget repositories?  (i.e. for separate branches of the same product)

@MatthewSkelton: A change to one package _always_ necessitates a changes to the projects/packages that consume it.  If you don't update the consumer, they will not get the enhancements and/or bug fixes.  When C changes, you MUST update B to test that it still works.  When B is updated, you MUST update A to test that it still works.  If you're fixing a bug in A and determine that the actual bug is in C, then you do exactly the steps outlined in the original post.

Comment: @JeffB Yes you can have as many local NuGet repositories as you want. At my current work place we have several for dev work (i.e. new features), one for QA work and one for the production branches.The only catch is that NuGet has an ordering for the repositories and will pull packages based on that ordering. So if a package exists in both dev and production and the dev repository is placed before the production repository then that package will always come from the dev repository. Normally not a problem if you follow a sensible versioning strategy (e.g. semver).

Comment: @JeffB You state that "A change to one package always necessitates a changes to the projects/packages that consume it. If you don't update the consumer, they will not get the enhancements and/or bug fixes."
The second statement is true, but that does not make your first statement correct. Part of the point of package management is that it decouples consumers from package changes.

Answer (score 7):

You have two choices here:

1. Run an instance of [NuGet Gallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery) within your organisation. This is the code which runs nuget.org
2. Get a license for [Artifactory Pro](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactorypro_overview), which has in-built Nuget support and acts as a Nuget repository.

I have used both, and #1 is a reasonable choice to start with, but NuGet Galley is optimised and designed for nuget.org, not on-premise/enterprise use, so things like deleting packages is a pain (hand-rolled SQL required).

I'd say that you should pay the (low) license fee for Artifactory Pro - it's an excellent product, and the JFrog team are really keen and switched on.

You should not be using nuget.org for internal/enterprise packages; nuget.org is designed for 3rd party/open source libraries, not internal build dependencies.

**EDIT**: in terms of workflow, why are you putting **shared** code into multiple packages? If the code needs to be shared, it needs to go in its own separate package.

**EDIT 2**: To speed up the code change workflow for the developer, you can use `nuget.exe` (the command-line client) and use command-line accessible builds, so you can target a "developer" build run. Then in your "developer" build (as opposed to the CI build) you specify -Source as a local path (e.g. `nuget install B -Source C:\Code\B`) when you want to pull the newly-updated `B` as a dependency and build against that; likewise for `C` or other local, newly-updated packages. Then when `A`, `B`, and `C` all build fine, you can `git push` all of them (in reverse dependency order), and let CI do its thing.

**However**, you also should question whether your package separation is really appropriate if you have to do this build 'dance' often, as this suggests that all the code should be in a single package, or possibly split along different lines in separate packages. A key feature of a well-defined package is that it should *not* cause ripple effects on other packages, certainly not if you are using [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) effectively.

**Edit 3** Some clarifications requested by marcelo-oliveira: "command-line accessible builds" are builds which can take place entirely from the command-line, without using Visual Studio, usually via batch files. A "developer build" is a build which a developer runs from her workstation, as opposed to the CI build which runs on the CI server (both builds should essentially be the same).

Comment: I think your point about correctly using Semantic Versioning is hugely important and easy to overlook. If a new version of `C` is designed to be backward-compatible - and versioned with that in mind - then you're right, there should be no knock-on effects and no cascade of updates. In particular, it shouldn't be necessary to update `B` before making new releases of `A`. I have some research to do around how this concept might interact with assembly strong names, but it's food for thought! I like the idea of specifying a "developer" package source for quick turnaround, too.

Comment: shambulator - I don't mind leaving the comment trail for others to see, but happy also to delete mine if you delete yours: your choice :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Edit 2? What do you mean by 'command-line accessible builds' and 'developer build'?

Comment: TeamCity also has the capability to act as a Nuget repo.  http://www.developerfusion.com/article/144809/continuous-integration-using-nuget-and-teamcity/

Comment: "You should not be using nuget.org" He never said he was using the official gallery, rendering the main part of your answer completely useless.

Comment: @user453441 "Completely useless" is rather strong, and also not very helpful. Do you have additional experience you can share?

Comment: @MatthewSkelton, nothing personal, it's just that a significant part of your answer says "use a private package repo" which is generally good advice but totally not what was asked. The question was about workflow when needing to make a change to a deep dependency. My comment is helpful in that it alerts others to stop upvoting a not so helpful answer.

Comment: I have the same question as the original poster, and the only useful part of this post is the 'EDIT 2' paragraph.  The rest sounds like a "don't do that" answer, which is less than helpful to anybody working on a non-trivial vertical-market application.

Answer (score 2):

**If A, B and C are under the same solution**, you can create NuGet packages for them in a single build.

Just make sure that the using package has the new version number (assuming your build doesn't randomly change it) of the package it depends on.

**If A, B and C are intentionally under different solutions** e.g. A is under an infrastructure solution and B is under a product solution, then the only suggestion I have for you is to define your CI builds run on check in and not periodically.

**Edit:**

Another option is to create a push **pre-release packages** (e.g. version 1.0.0-alpha) to your NuGet server during local builds, this way developers can experiment with the package prior to creating a release version.

Comment: There are various tools for automating the package creations during builds, include one I built.

Answer (score 0):

Nuget was designed for sharing third party libaries. We plan to use Nuget internally for all common code that can be shared between projects. Things like a common data layer, string and other regular expression functions, email components and other artifacts like that.

The only way I see Nuget being of any help is when the components, code or artifacts you are sharing across teams/projects are stable and have their own release cycle that is different from your project's release cycle. For your needs Nuget is an overkill. You might have better productivity linking all such projects within the same solution. Your solution structure should include the three projects A,B and C as dependent projects referenced internally wherever required.

Comment: The 'single-solution' approach simplifies a lot, but does not scale well.  Microsoft recommends breaking your solution apart when it passes 50 projects (medium-size application).  Short of checking in binaries, Nuget seems to be the next best thing, even if painful.

Comment: What do you think about sharing the source code in the form of subrepositories (with Git/Mercurial) instead of compiled DLLs via NuGet, if we're talking about libraries?

Comment: @user20358 totally agree... not worth the time and effort if the packages frequently and do not have their own release cycle. I'm experimenting GitSubmodules, will see

Comment: @Gokulnath how did it go with submodules? I'm dealing with the same issue/pain

Comment: @A.K submodules worked out well. We used it until the packages were stable enough and then switched to internal NuGet. GitSubmodules work out well when all your dependent apps should be referencing the same version, and we had difficulties referencing different versions (or branches) in different apps. We are currently experimenting NuKeeper https://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuKeeperForAutomatedNuGetPackageReferenceUpdatesOnBuildServers.aspx