# What are the advantages of using Nuget automatic package restore in the enterprise?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I've been trying to implement a Nuget policy inside my company and I was wondering what is the real value of Automatic Package Restore when working on internal projects on a internally hosted TFS.

I understand that in OpenSource projects or when using externally hosted source control not checking in external packages can save a lot of disk space, but apart from this advantage (saving disk space on the server) I cannot see any other advantage in using the automatic restore: actually it gives us some problem as the build machine doesn't connect to internet and for using that feature we'd either change firewall rules or keeping a local cache of the nuget repository.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steven indicated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22457995/539846) the main reason for keeping the packages out of source control is to reduce the amount of data that needs to be stored by and transferred from/to the source control server. Obviously in a company where you control all the hardware neither the disk space nor the network transfer should be an issue, but why waste the disk space / time dealing with the packages if you don't need to. Note that the size of the package directory can be a quite considerable percentage of the total size of a workspace. In my case the packages directory takes up between 80% - 95% of the total workspace when using TFS (for my work workspaces) and between 50% - 75% for my private workspaces (which are based on git and thus have the .git directory which takes up some space). All in all a significant amount of space could be saved on your source control server if you use package restore.

One way to solve the access problem with Nuget.org is to have your own [local package repository](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds). This local package repository could be a local [nuget](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery) [web](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetForTheEnterpriseNuGetInAContinuousIntegrationAutomatedBuildSystem.aspx) [service](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/10/21/hosting-your-own-local-and-remote-nupack-feeds.aspx/) or just a shared directory on a server. Because the repository lives inside your company LAN it should not be a big problem for the build server to get to the local nuget repository.
A side benefit of this approach is that your build process is independent from Nuget.org (in the very rare case it goes down) and, more importantly, that you know exactly which packages get pulled into the build (because they will be the approved packages in your local repository).

For us the decision whether to use a local nuget repository and the package restore option depended on our decision to package all our internal libraries as nuget packages (I have described our development process in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18179486/539846) to another nuget question). Because of that we needed a local package repository to distribute those internal packages. Which then meant that adding the third-party packages to this repository was easy and thus using package restore made perfect sense. 
If you don't package your internal libraries as nuget packages then you will put those in your source control along side your solution and code files. In that case you may as well do the same for the third-party libraries.

In the end it is all a trade-off. Disk space vs ease of infrastructure set-up etc. etc. Pick the solution that suits your environment best.

Comment: Thank you... we are also debating the usage of Nuget to host internal shared libraries: how do you solve the problem of debugging libs that come from Nuget without having the source code to step in if needed.

Comment: @CodeClimber For debugging of our own libraries we set up a symbol server (not very hard to do) and for third-party packages we use [SymbolSource.org](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/21/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-to-step-into-microsoft-net-source-code.aspx). Obviously not all third-party packages publish their PDBs but in that case you wouldn't find them in the downloads. If you really want them you could always grab the source, build it, store the packages locally and push the symbols into your local symbol server.

Comment: I was referring to one's own libraries. Thx

Answer (score 1):

[From Nuget.org](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages#Using_NuGet_without_committing_packages_to_source_control):

> The original NuGet workflow has been to commit the Packages folder into source control. The reasoning is that it matches what developers typically do when they don't have NuGet: they create a `Lib` or `ExternalDependencies` folder, dump binaries into there and commit them to source control to allow others to build.

So the idea is that the packages would be restored on each machine that the project would be built upon so the binary data stays out of source control. And with distributed source control systems like Mercurial or Git, that is disk space and bandwidth that get's used on client machines as well as the server.

But that does pose a problem when your build machine can't connect to the internet to nuget.org (I'm assuming). I think you've hit the major solutions. Commit the packages to source control and avoid package restore, allow the build machine to connect to the internet, or setup a local mirror.

I'll stop short of saying there are no advantages of package restore in your environment. I don't see big harm in committing the packages. But it really depends on how your team functions, what your team expects and what type of enterprise environment you're working in.