# unable to link header and cpp file of one project's from another LNK2019: unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, linker, extern

I have a header file A.h

```
namespace DIV
{
    int Fun();
}
```

A source file A.cpp

```
namespace DIV
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        A(){}
        ~A(){}    
        int Fun();    
    };


    int A::Fun()
    {
        return 0;
    }        
}
```

Now I have another source file B.cpp in another project of the same solution.

This source uses google's GTest framework. Inside the test function I use

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "A.h"
TEST(FunTest, Param)
{
    int value = DIV::Fun();
}
```

Because of the `DIV::Fun()` call I get linker error. I don't understand the reason behind the linker error.

**EDIT:** B.cpp is in an .exe project and A.h/cpp is in a lib project.

Comment: did you compile the execute file with the  A.cpp ?

Comment: can you show us the makefile ?

Comment: I have compiled it with the project that contains the `B.cpp` file. Note that `A.cpp`, `A.h` is in one project and `B.cpp` is in another. I don't have a make file. I don't know how to make one. Sorry.

Comment: I have even renamed the Fun() function that is not a member of class A. But still the error remains!!

Comment: What is the exact symbol that the linker gives in the error message?  What is the linker command line? What does `link /dump /symbols A.obj | grep Fun` and `link /dump /symbols B.obj | grep Fun` say?

Comment: this is the exact error message `B.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl DIV::CallFun(void)" (?CallFun@PAL@AFE@@YAGXZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall FunTest_Param_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@FunTest_Param_Test@@EAEXXZ)`  This is after I renamed the Fun()(not a member of class A) to CallFun(). And I don't understand what is a linker command line and also the commands you mentioned here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved. I have got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398009/linking-error-for-not-being-able-to-link-header-file-to-cpp-file-correctly/22401156?noredirect=1#22401156). To summarize I needed to link my exe project with the lib project which contains the function `fun()`. Now the simplest way to make the .exe project link against .lib project probably is by adding a reference:

- In the .exe project's settings, select the section named "Common Properties" at the top of the section list.
- You should now see a list of references that the .exe project has. The list is probably empty.
- Click the "Add new reference" button at the bottom of the dialog and add the .lib project as a reference
- When you select the new reference in the list of references you will see a set of properties for that reference. Make sure that the property called "Link Library Dependencies" is set to true. This will cause the .lib project to be added automatically as an input to the linker when you build the .exe project.

After that the linker error was gone.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been looking for this for ages!  Well formatted answer too.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of your use of `extern` here? Because functions have external linkage by default, marking functions `extern` for this reason is not necessary. However, this should not cause a linker error in this case.

The linker error indicates that the function definition is found but the object file is not properly linked. How are you compiling and linking the program?

EDIT:

Since A.cpp is not in the same project as B.cpp, you will need to explicitly link to the object files in your A.cpp project. Since it sounds like you are using Visual Studio, you may find this useful

[How do you share code between projects/solutions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Sorry. I edited my post. Even when I remove the `extern` keyword linking error doesn't go away. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain about what do you mean by linking a program?

Comment: When you build a program, each file is compiled to an object file, then these object files are linked to create your executable program. An error like this indicates that the linker failed to find that function in any of the object files.

Answer (score 0):

With extern and without extern keyword it works. You need to export your function **fun** to other modules/projects. Use **__declspec(dllexport)** .