# Use C++ API in C# Project

Tags: c#, c++, language-interoperability, managed-code, autodesk-navisworks

Is it possible to use a C++ API (series of Header files and CPP files) in a C# project?

Maybe its possible to compile these files into `.obj` or `.lib` files and include them in the Visual C# project? Something similar is done for `Crypto++`.

If it is possible, are there any drawbacks from this?

Context and import information:

- The C++ API is called NWCreate and is developed by Autodesk Navisworks
- I am using Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2010
- We have a large existing code base in C# where much of the operations we will perform in the navisworks plugin are already coded in C# (from other Autodesk projects we have produced). So having to rewrite all those operations in C++ is very much reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is best solution. It worked well for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/34541336/5732839

Answer (score 1):

at least , you have 2 method to invoke C/C++ API from .NET:

- Compile the C/C++ API as dll, then use PInvoke to call it from .NET
- Use Managed C++ (VC++), then use IJW to wrap the native code, IJW will generate managed code that can call directly from .NET