# Reference to WCF classes in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, reference

I have two projects in my Solution. *Windows phone Silverlight 8.1 Application* and *WCF service project*. In my WCF project I have some classes that are used in WCF and they also should be used on client side in Windows Phone app. So I want to add a reference to my WCF project. So I right-click on my WP project and select *add reference*. Then I choose *Solution->Projects->and select my wcf* project and I get following error:

[image]

How can I add a reference to WCF project in my Windows Phone Silverlight application? Because I'm guessing that this is the best way to consume classes from WCF in my WP project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Phone project targets a different framework than the WCF one -- so neither can reference the other.  You can either:

1. Use the auto-generated client proxy that Visual Studio creates when you use "Add Service Reference".
2. Create a shared project that both WCF and WP projects reference.  The shared project can be either a [PCL (Portable Class Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), an [RIA project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707371%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) -- or just simply two projects that target the separate frameworks, and [share the same set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382768/1001985).

I think #2 using a PCL is preferable, but YMMV.

Comment: Oh I tried to add shared project as you said - PCL. But neither can be added, WP project nor WCF. The error says: *Portable Library projects can only be reference other Portable Library projects and assemblies.*