# How to integrate/merge multiple ASP.NET Core MVC applications into one

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core-mvc, integration

I would like to know how can I integrate multiple ASP.NET Core MVC applications into one.

Let me explain my problem.

I have the project `MainProject` that would be used in multiple applications. This project contains:

- Typescript,
- CSS
- image
- Controllers/Models/Views

I have another project `ProjectA` that would be used just in some applications. This project would contain as well as the `MainProject` those type of files.

In my `FinalProject`, I want to integrate these files of these two projects.

I need to be able to access to all controllers, Typescript, CSS,  images, etc. from my `FinalProject`.

How can I do that?

Is there any way to add some kind of reference to these type of files or export theme in any way ?

I have created these projects:

- ASP.NET Core MVC `MainProject`
- ASP.NET Core MVC `ProjectA`
- ASP.NET Core MVC `FinalProject`

In my `FinalProject` I have added a project reference to `MainProject` and `ProjectA`.

This way, I can access all controllers from these two projects, but I can't access any Typescript, CSS or image files.

Comment: You could share controllers, views, Razor Pages and more with Application Parts,the document related :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: here's an issue related with sharing css/js files between projects:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596864/how-to-share-css-and-js-files-of-one-project-in-another-using-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ruikai Feng. Create a Nuget package that includes the common files looks interesting.  I'll try this way.