# Use a controller from a different Solution

Tags: c#, boilerplate, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to use a controller and a partial view from another soluction.
[image: IMG1]

I wanna to use one of the controller and a partial view inside the management solution in the shell solution. Is that possible?

Comment: See: [How do you share code between projects/solutions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I can't use Dll's

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.