# How to include my file in other Projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I couldnt find a way to do this:

i.e. i have   `myFuncions.cs` file somewhere in my pc (i.e. `D:\myFuncions.cs`)

I might update this file everyday (add other methods). I want to include/reference that file in different solutions/projects (but not using "import" way, but always including that source file directly).

Comment: Are you after c or c#? Your tag contradicts with file extension.

Comment: When you add the file, in the VS add file window, you can click the drop down next to the “Add” button and choose to add as “Link” instead.

Comment: @YurySchkatula sorry, `.cs`, yes

Comment: @blins thanks, found! please post it as answer!

Comment: @blins you've hepled me. just post it as answer, because my question name is quite different, and then we can mark it as dupicalte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the file, in the VS add file window, you can click the drop down next to the “Add” button and choose to add as “Add as Link” instead. Then the file can be shared across multiple projects/solutions.

There is a similar answer here although the question is broader: [How do you share code between projects/solutions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio)

Comment: also, add note - include this image.  https://i.imgur.com/K5dRZEA.png