# How do I link a source file between two proejcts in Visual Studio Code or dotnet command line?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I have some common code between two project solutions, and I would like to link a source file from one solution to another. Specifically, I would like to add/link a single .cs file from a different solution to my current one.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio) seems to be a good answer. However, Visual Studio Code does not have the `add as link` or `add existing item`. It only have `Add Folder to Workplace`. Furthermore,`dotnet add` and `dotnet sln add` only takes .csproj file, which is the whole project.

So how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally don't share sources files because it creates all sorts of problems.

What we do is put the code in a *class library* and share the *project* (or assembly) with anything that needs it