# Referencing a solution inside another solution C#

Tags: c#

I am new at C#. I am creating a project that contains two solutions and I cannot reference one from the other.  I need to use the classes that are in the `AssestManagment` to `ManejoDeActivos`. Is it possible to reference based on the screenshot below?

[Reference other Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tfLt.png)

Technically, the project "ManejoDeActivos" is to have only the front end of the applicaction. It has the GUI. The AssestManagment project connects to a database, which will allow to add information to the DB. Inside the "ManejoDeActivos" we have a GUI that allow to add a new asset through a form. I having problems calling the Assest class that will allow to create a new object of an asset. I tried to add AssestManagment to ManejoDeActivos, however when I go to references I do not see the AssestManagment project and if I tried to browse it in my computer the project solution is not showing up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you share code between projects/solutions in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio)

Comment: It would help knowing why you want to reference the solution. What will that accomplish?

Comment: Technically, the project "ManejoDeActivos" is to have only the front end of the applicaction. It has the GUI. The AssestManagment project connects to a database, which will allow to add information to the DB. Inside the "ManejoDeActivos" we have a GUI that allow to add a new asset through a form. I having problems calling the Assest class that will allow to create a new object of an asset. I tried to add AssestManagment to ManejoDeActivos, however when I go to references I do not see the AssestManagment project and if I tried to browse it in my computer the project solution is not showing up

Answer (score 0):

You could take the code needed from one of the solutions/projects, put it into a class library project, and compile it into a DLL. You can then reference that DLL inside of another project and access the code.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach will be to reference all the projects of the old solution on the new solution.
It might be cumbersome as the number of projects increase but would accomplish what I’m thinking you’re trying to accomplish.